# sql lite Transaction locked

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, transactions

I'm trying to use beginTransaction() in sqllite database when reading excel file but i face some problem  get error the database is locked

this is my edit .
note i'm using this code five time to insert 5 excel files

code :

```
        dbHandler.open();
    try {
        url = new URL(
                "http://ictfox.com/Hafil_Updates/ImportExcel/schoolmaster.csv");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                url.openStream(), "Windows-1256"));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] insertValues = line.split(",");
            if (flag_is_header) {

                dbHandler = new MySQLiteHelper(context);

                long row = dbHandler.insertSchoolMaster(insertValues[0],
                        insertValues[1], insertValues[2], insertValues[3],
                        insertValues[4], insertValues[5]);
                Log.e("no. of rows inserted", "" + row);

            } else {
                flag_is_header = true;
            }
        }
  dbHandler.setsucss();
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        dbHandler.end();
        dbHandler.close();
    }
    return line;
}

    public void open()
{

    sqliteDB=this.getWritableDatabase();
    sqliteDB.beginTransaction();

}

     public void setsucss() {


 sqliteDB.setTransactionSuccessful();

}


// Close Database 
public void end() {


 sqliteDB.endTransaction();

}
```

Comment: post your logcat and format your code.

Comment: Do you have many threads accessing the database?

Comment: 5 methods access the database one after another after close

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode

Comment: I can't see any "excel files". Your code handles csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your transaction like:

```
db.beginTransaction(); 
try{
//Process inserts
//....
db.setTransactionSuccessful(); 
}catch(Exception e){

}finally{
db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: i have used all of these in open statment and close

Comment: The pattern is important, also you can track down which thread is causing problems using DDMS :http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

Comment: where to put db.close();

Comment: Do you have a singleton? You might as well want to use a content provider. It gets messy without either of the one. You can close the db once all your DB operations are done.  I never call this method personally, here is the reference:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/nopkaw4UZ9U/cPfPL3uW7nQJ

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to use database transaction in Android:

1. `beginTransaction()`-- to start the transaction
2. `setTransactionSuccessful()` -- to commit the transaction,it will commit the values in the database
3. `endTransaction()`-- to end your database transaction.

NOTE : If you start the transaction, you need to close the transaction.

Here is the standard idiom for transactions:

```
db.beginTransaction();
   try {
     ...
     db.setTransactionSuccessful();
   } finally {
     db.endTransaction();
   }
```

Refer : SQLiteDatabse

Example :

```
mDatabase.beginTransaction();
try{
  //do multiple database operations here
  //which throws exceptions on error
  mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
  //do not any more database operations between
  //setTransactionSuccessful and endTransaction
  }catch(Exception e){
    //end the transaction on error too when doing exception handling
    mDatabase.endTransaction();
    throw e;
  }
  //end the transaction on no error
  mDatabase.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you provide the link? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html